# Call .sel() on xarray DataArrayGroupBy object

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a DataArray with two dimensions, "a" and "b":

```
foo = xr.DataArray(np.random.normal(size=(5, 40)), dims=["a", "b"], coords=dict(a=range(5), b=range(40)))
```

I use `groupby_bins` to create 2 groups at `a=0` for different b.

```
foo_grouped = foo.groupby_bins(foo.sel(a=0), bins=2)
```

Now I want to select, for the two groups, certain values for a: `a=slice(5, 10)`

I would like to call something like `foo_grouped_sel = foo_grouped.sel(a=slice(5, 10))` that should return a `DataArrayGroupby`, because in later steps, I'd like to call, e.g., `foo_grouped_sel.mean()`.

But `.sel()` is not supported for `DataArrayGroupby`. Is there a workaround (other than call `groupby_bins` several times)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you select before calling groupby? If not, could you explain more about why not and what you’re trying to do, e.g. by showing us your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think selecting before calling groupby, e.g., `foo.sel(a=1).groupby_bins(foo.sel(a=0), bins=2)` would work. If there is no other way, I will do that. However, in my problem, I create a `GroupbyDataset` first and apply lots of different operations later on. For example, I would appreciate also a .resample() function that operates on groupby objects. I could always apply the operations first before calling groupby, but logically that makes less sense to me? I'd prefer creating groups (in my case: clusters of forecasts) first and analyzing these groups later.

Comment: creating groupby objects is pretty cheap. so I think the fact that you can do it before or after the groupby().agg operation provides you with good options, and the xarray devs didn't think groupby.sel().agg was needed, and I'd tend to agree. whether it's more efficient to subset first and then do the groupby().agg or vice versa is workflow dependent but it's probably worth experimenting with this a bit if performance is a big concern.

Comment: alright, I see. It feels a bit suboptimal for me that in order to do 5 operations (e.g., resampling, correlations, selection and averaging, ...), I need to call the same groupby function 5 times instead of grouping just once and then applying the calculations. Anyway, I guess there is some underlying reason for this. - thanks for your reply!

Comment: I mean you can always apply a custom reduction  that slices…